# How to construct a packet of 20 bits in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, packet

I am new in Omnet++. I was wondering how to construct a packet of pre defined bits in Omnet++?

Answer (score 0):

Define your packet in a message file (.msg) and then use that message class when creating a packet.

https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def